# Can I use Admob, if I will publish my android app on another app stores other than Google play store?

Tags: android, admob

Can I use Admob, if I will publish my android app on another app stores other than Google play store? I have my android app but if I want to publish it other android markets except Google play market then it is possible to me go with admob advertisement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is ok if the terms of the other stores allow it; which they typically do.

Comment: Thank adavis, do you have such experience. You know such markets. Please share.

Comment: Yes, I use Admob in one of my apps and it's available on Google Play and Amazon App Store.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terms of use of app-stores and advertisement plattforms and not programming